# Maven doesn't resolve indirect dependencies which from private repo

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I have a problem about maven. I just use m2e with eclipse mars, maven version is 3.3.3. It couldn't resolve indirect dependencies from my nexus private repository.

For example, there are 3 projects: common-A, common-B, biz-X.

- Both common-A and common-B deployed in nexus private repo as jar.
- common-B depends common-A. biz-X depends common-B. So biz-X indirect depends common-A.
- biz-X project does download common-B successfully.

The problem is, biz-X couldn't download common-A.jar.

Anyone help me! Thx!

---

update1:

I have some progress, here is m2e's stacktrace:

```
org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for (my groupId):common-B:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:349)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.readArtifactDescriptor(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:218)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.resolveCachedArtifactDescriptor(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:535)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.getArtifactDescriptorResult(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:519)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:409)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.processDependency(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:363)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.process(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:351)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultDependencyCollector.collectDependencies(DefaultDependencyCollector.java:254)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.collectDependencies(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:316)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultProjectDependenciesResolver.java:172)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.resolveDependencies(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:215)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:188)
at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:119)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.readMavenProject(MavenImpl.java:636)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.resolveProjectDependencies(DefaultMavenDependencyResolver.java:63)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refreshPhase2(ProjectRegistryManager.java:529)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:491)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager$3.call(ProjectRegistryManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:495)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:350)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.registry.ProjectRegistryManager.refresh(ProjectRegistryManager.java:297)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration0(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:398)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:345)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager$2.call(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:1)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.executeBare(MavenExecutionContext.java:176)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:151)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenExecutionContext.execute(MavenExecutionContext.java:99)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.embedder.MavenImpl.execute(MavenImpl.java:1351)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.project.ProjectConfigurationManager.updateProjectConfiguration(ProjectConfigurationManager.java:342)
at org.eclipse.m2e.core.ui.internal.UpdateMavenProjectJob.runInWorkspace(UpdateMavenProjectJob.java:77)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact (my groupId):root:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in public (http://192.168.1.35:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:177)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:226)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParentExternally(DefaultModelBuilder.java:978)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.readParent(DefaultModelBuilder.java:796)
at org.apache.maven.model.building.DefaultModelBuilder.build(DefaultModelBuilder.java:325)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.loadPom(DefaultArtifactDescriptorReader.java:340)
... 33 moreCaused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Could not find artifact (my groupId):root:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in public (http://192.168.1.35:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:444)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:246)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:223)
at org.apache.maven.repository.internal.DefaultModelResolver.resolveModel(DefaultModelResolver.java:173)
... 38 moreCaused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find artifact (my groupId):root:pom:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in public (http://192.168.1.35:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:893)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$2.wrap(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:1)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector$GetTask.flush(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:673)
at io.takari.aether.connector.AetherRepositoryConnector.get(AetherRepositoryConnector.java:310)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:520)
at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:421)
... 41 more
```

It seems that maven says she couldn't read the common-B's pom file. But I found there is a pom.xml included in downloaded common-B.jar, location is:

> /META-INF/maven/(some package)/common-B/pom.xml

It is actually the pom which I defined in root dir of project common-B.
But why maven does not load it?
Or if this pom file is not what maven needs?
Or if the pom file needs download from private repo? If it is, I've found common-B-0.0.1-yyyyMMdd.(maybe it's some seq).pom in the same location of jar file in correct nexus repo dir, maven cound't load it? Is it because I deploy the artifact as SNAPSHOT type?
Or is there some op do I needs to do around the "mvn deploy" op?

Those are clue above. Hope they're useful.

---

update2:

Oh my .... I must kidding me. I found the reason. because there is a root pom I've forgot to deploy, both common artifacts extend it. Now the problem solved. Thank you guys!

Comment: what are the scopes of the dependencies?

Comment: They are all <scope>compile</scope>

Answer (score 0):

You need to add both Release repository URL as well as SNAPSHOT repository URLs to the pom.xml (or) settings.xml

Please try adding both URLs as specified in Link:
[Adding Snapshot Repo to pom.xml](http://kamwo.me/java-maven-add-snapshot-repository-to-pom/)

Comment: Thanks, but it's not my problem, the problem has been solved. see update2.